# asynchronous javascript functions

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

so I am trying to call the google geocoder to get some values but I am do not fully understand what I can and cant do within the realm of asynchronous functions.  There is another example on SO that helped me set this up like so, but I still cannot figure out how to get those values into an array

Here is my call to the geocoder:

```
function getLng(name,func){
     geocoder.geocode( {'address': name}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        func(results[0].geometry.location.lng());
      } else {
        alert("Something got wrong " + status);
      }
    });
}
```

here is the building of an array using the geocoder values:

```
('.action').click(funciton(){
     var homes =[];
     homes.push({name: Name,
                type: "dwelling",
                lat: getLat(Name, function(location){return location;}),
                lng: getLng(Name, function(location){return location;})
            });
  console.log(homes);
});
```

Sincere thanks for any help... It is greatly appriciated.

Comment: did you make it works?

Answer (score 0):

Asynchronous functions do not return the result immediately, they usually work by emitting events, passing a callback as argument, or returning a promise object.
In your example, you are passing a callback that returns its argument into the void.

Also you wouldn't want to call the geocoder API twice for the same address.

A better function to declare would be :

```
function getGeoLocation(address, onDoneCallback) { ... }
...
var homes = [];
getGeoLocation(some_address, function(loc) {
    homes.push({lat : loc.lat, lng : loc.lng});
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's not quite as straight-forward as this. The OP is trying to build the `homes` object with more than just the address lat/long. They also want to keep the address and the type of address in the object too

Comment: thanks a lot @G Roy. That was going into the void. And haha, I am acutally calling it three times here (but you're right, one of those times is unecessary)... What I am doing is getting a click position, then getting the town of the click, then calling again to get the center of that town or whatever (I left out a lot of code). Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0):

Using `async` methods means a dramatic re-think of how you code your events. Using async means that the code never waits for a method to complete, instead it moves ahead to the next line immediately. This means you have to move your assign code (`homes = ...`) into the success handlers

Note that the click event is now restricted to only calling the `getGeoCoords` function. 
This function now has a callback method called `onSuccess` which is responsible for building the `homes` object based on the results of the async query

```
var homes = [];

('.action').click(function(){
    getGeoCoords(Name, 'dwelling');
});

function getGeoCoords(name, type){

    var onSuccess = function(results){
        var home = {};

        home.name = name;                   // getGeoCoods parameter 'name'
        home.type = type;                   // getGeoCoods parameter 'type'
        home.lat  = results.lat;            // result of async query
        home.lng  = results.lng;            // result of async query

        homes.push(home);                   // push object to global array 
    }

    geocoder.geocode( 
        {'address': name},                  // async query options
        onSuccess                           // success callback
    );
}
```

Comment: @ambe5960 great! If this answer helped you, please mark it up